# Is it possible to setup own DNS-server for company behind proxy?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

I've got a general question about hosting own dns-server for the company behind a proxy-server (also hosted in the same network) and the ability to access them from outside these network.

For example: if someone is searching for example.com and I'm the owner of this domain and I host the coressponding DNS-server by myself inside the network of my company behind a proxy-server, could be my domain resolved by my own DNS or will there be some conflicts with the proxy?

Many thanks in advice.

Comment: What do you mean with "proxy" server? There are no proxy servers in DNS.

Comment: @Tom There is nothing that technically prevents proxying DNS requests. It just isn't something you'd usually do. It could quickly become complicated. Instead you'd usually use a DNS recursor, forwarders, or zone transfers depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Got any examples of DNS proxy servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host a DNS domain which is able to be resolved publicly, then the authoritative DNS server needs to be reachable on the public network. In your example, the root servers for ".com" would have records to point requests for "example.com" to your nameserver(s), telling public resolvers which nameserver to query for authoritative answers for the domain. If the public resolver cannot reach your nameserver directly, then they will never be able to complete lookups for anything in the "example.com" domain.

It's not clear why the proxy server would matter in this scenario. If you internal network is "private" (such as using RFC1918 addresses) and internal clients can only reach sites on the internet via the proxy, then no, your internal nameserver probably won't work. I'm not sure what purpose your proxy serves, however.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! 
At the end for securtiy purpose, I want to handle my proxy as the single gateway to enter my network and the other way round. So my DNS-servers would be inside this private network and all traffic would go through my proxy and from there forward to the destination clients aka DNS, when a domain resolution is required. 
Is it possible to handle the scenario on this way?

I hope it's a little bit better for you to understand...thanks for your replies!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a proxy server to do the job of a proper firewall. I'm afraid this isn't going to work, as DNS doesn't use proxy servers.

Comment: Okay, again, thank you very much for your help!
I thought, because a proxy server and a firewall are acting on different layers of the OSI-network-modell, it would be usefull to configure both. A proper proxy and firewall. 
So if I understand you right, I can use a proxy to access the web with my private network, but my DNS-servers have to be outside of this configuration setup?

Comment: If your internal network is using private addressing, then your authoritative nameservers (you must deploy at least 2 servers if you want them to be authoritative for your domain) should either be in a DMZ segment off of your firewall, or on a hardened bastion host outside of the firewall. No matter how you do it, they MUST be directly reachable (on both TCP *and* UDP ports 53) from hosts on the public internet. More requirements for hosting authoratative nameservers can be [found at IANA here](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements).